# Why do I get Attribute Error in python while creating a class objects

Tags: python, class, object, initialization, attributeerror

What may I do if i constantly have AttributeError. It keeps saying 'User' object has no attribute. Is there any declarations i have to make again?

This is my code:

```
class User:
   def_init_(self, name, email, age):
     self.name = name
     self.email = email
     self.age = age

def greeting(self):
  return f' My name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years, you can contact me on my email{self.email}'

kay= User('Kayboy',      'kayboy@gmail.com', 18)

print(kay.greeting())
```

Comment: This shouldn't even run because `def_init_(self, name, email, age):` is invalid syntax. Please make sure that your question contains the exact code with correct indentation. And please provide the full and exact error message.

Comment: under the right conditions (see comment of Matthias) you can get what you want with by calling method as a function which accept an object as parameter: `greeting(kay)`

Answer (score 1):

You might have done an error of indentation.
Bad code :

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age

def greeting(self):
    return f'My name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years, you can contact me on my email{self.email}'

kay= User('Kayboy', 'kayboy@gmail.com', 18)
print(kay.greeting())
```

Here greeting is a standalone function, not part of your User class. And you have attribute error calling `kay.greeting`

Correct code :

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, email, age):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.age = age

    def greeting(self):
      return f'My name is {self.name} and I am {self.age} years, you can contact me on my email{self.email}'

kay= User('Kayboy', 'kayboy@gmail.com', 18)
print(kay.greeting())
```